# Difference between void and non-void functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, memory

I have simple question

Let's say I have two functions in C++:

```
void DoSomething();
```

and

```
bool DoSomething();
```

Is there any difference in memory or speed between these two functions?

And second question, related to first: I suppose that there is speed difference, as bool has to return some value. But I don't have to use return value at all. So, would it be good for me to declare DoSomething() as bool, just in case I decided to return something in the future?

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: The difference is likely to be negligible - what's prompting your concern?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your function has no reason to return something, it shouldn't return anything, i.e., it should return `void`. There is no point in giving a function which doesn't produce any result an artificial return value.

If you function has a reason to return something, e.g., because it can fail, it should return the corresponding result. Since the result will be meaningful, it won't be ignored, i.e., there is no optimization potential for not returning value.

Where things do become interesting is when returning massive objects: the potential copy happening may be expensive and there is also a speed advantage with respect to reusing memory. However, these considerations don't apply to any of built-in types.

Comment: Also note that even the “potential copy” is pretty much rare. Most data types can be moved and otherwise the compiler will usually apply RVO.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of memory and speed, the difference between void DoSomething(); and bool DoSomething(); is likely negligible. Choosing between them depends on the function's intended purpose: use void for actions without a return value and bool if you foresee needing to convey a boolean result. The unused return value may not significantly impact performance, but it's good practice to align the return type with the expected behavior of the function.